# I have a problem using onMarkerClickListeners. I am a beginner and there is an error appearing that says Missing return statement

Tags: android

I am getting that error in the last Override.

I really do not know what I need to return so please help me.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker myMarker;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng MORNAR = new LatLng(43.5201139, 16.4282208);
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);


        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MORNAR).title("Stari mornar"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(MORNAR));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MORNAR, 13));




    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        String name= marker.getTitle();

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Stari mornar"))
        {
            openActivity3();
        }

    }
    public void openActivity3(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The on marker click returns a bool [handled, I think ]

Answer (score 1):

Change the maker click listener to this

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    String name= marker.getTitle();

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Stari mornar"))
    {
        openActivity3();

        return true;
    }
   return false;

}
```

Here the method shows that it returns boolean.

So if you click the marker and the function returns true, that means the click event is successful, and if it returns false info windows will show as usual.

Answer (score -1):

In the last override method (onMapReady(Marker)) you need to return a boolean, since it is mandatory.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    String name= marker.getTitle();

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Stari mornar"))
    {
        openActivity3();
    }

    // return true or false
}
```

If you return true, that means you have clicked on the marker.

After the privacy accessor of your function ("public") you have your returning type, which is boolean in this case.

Let me know if this helped! ;)